# FLVPlayBack component, how to built-in skin in project?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

FLVPlayBack asks a link for it's skin. How can I bult-in skin in project, so I will have only one swf in result?

Answer (score 0):

if you are using flex or CS4 and above you could try using the Embed directive and point the skin at that.